# How to Render the CONTENTS of a Precompiled JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rendering

This might not be a common question, but I do need this feature.

In my controller, I want to render a JavaScript file, named `ApplicationLike.js` with the following:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require rr/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
//= (other requires)
```

and then in my controller, there is an `inject` action, I want to render the CONTENTS of the precompiled `ApplicationLike.js`, because it will be used as the `src` attribute of the following:

```
<script src="//localhost:3000/app/inject.js/"></script>
```

We cannot use `javascript_include_tag`, because it will include the javascript tag `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`, which will cause syntax error, because we just need the PURE JavaScript contents for the `src` attribute of the above ALREADY-EXISTING `<script>` tag.

I'm not sure if you guys understand what I'm talking about.

I googled for more than 5 or 8 hours, no luck.

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

NOTE: `redirect_to /assets/ApplicationLike.js` will work, but I need to render more lines of JavaScript code that contains dynamic Ruby variables (for example `current_user.id`).

BUT: of course, we can use a view called `inject.js.erb` that contains both the contents of `ApplicationLike.js` and more lines of JavaScript code as I mentioned.  I just don't know how to render JUST the CONTENTS of the precompiled `ApplicationLike.js` JavaScript file.

Comment: If i understand you right you will be able to access some user data in your javascript. In your case I would create an script tag with somthing like this `<script>window.currentUser = <%= current_user.as_json %>;</script>`

Comment: Yes, I could get `<%= current_user %>` in my inject.js.erb file, and I do NOT need the `<script>` tag.  BUT I also have to include another JavaScript file called `/assets/ApplicationLike.js`, I only need the PURE JavaScript CONTENTS of that file (of course the precompiled/compiled CONTENTS), that is, I CANNOT use `<%= javascript_include_tag 'ApplicationLike' %>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able just to read it and display its contents, like so...

```
<%= File.open(Rails.root.join('app' , 'inject.js'), 'rb').read %>
```

If you want the compiled contents, try something like this:

```
<% files = Dir[Rails.root.join('public' , 'assets'), '*.js'].keep_if {|f| f =~ /application-\w{32}\.js/i } %>
<%= File.open(files.first, 'rb').read if files.present? %>
```

Comment: I need the PURE CONTENTS of the precompiled JavaScript assets file `ApplicationLike.js`. If we directly File.open.read `ApplicationLike.js`, it will give us the original file contents, which still contains `//= require rr/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js`

Comment: Wouldn't that be "the PURE CONTENTS of the precompiled JavaScript assets file"? Do you mean compiled results?

Comment: Oh, the English word `Precompiled` is very confusing.  Yes, you are right, I need the compiled CONTENTS to be loaded to the client, that is, no `//=require ...`.

Comment: OK, you should be able to do the same thing, but more like `<%= File.open(Rails.root.join('public' , 'assets' , 'application.js'), 'rb').read %>` (or wherever your path is for compiled assets. Just look at the source in production mode, if you don't know where the compiled file is located.

Comment: hmmm, how about the fingerprint of the compiled `ApplicationLike.js` file?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you... do you mean a md5, or the etag, or something?

Comment: If it's a compiled assets JavaScript file, it's filename will be appended a fingerprint in production mode, right? Then how can I know the filename to `File.open` ?

Comment: See the updated answer for how you might accomplish something like that.

Comment: (I forgot that Rails 4 does not create the non-digest version) It seems like there should be an easier way to find the path to that file, but I could not.